# facing error while installing google android studio, require jdk

Tags: java, android

---

**Restarted the computer after JDK installation. Problem solved. thanks**

---

---

I am trying to install Android Studio, it is require JDK version 1.7 or higher.

Downloaded this: 
android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe 
jdk-8u25-windows-i586.exe

Installed jdk first: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe

Now installing android which asking for JDK, provided that jdk folder. 
showing this problem:

[image: screenshot of android studio installation]

any help? 
:) advance thanks. 
Desktop Computer with win7 32.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try selecting the root folder and not the bin folder? That would be my guess. Hope this helps.

Comment: i am not sure what happened but, i restarted the computer and now it is installing! thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have downloaded wrong `JDK`. You need to download `JDK` for `Oracle`. Your downloaded JDK has no `bin` or `java.exe` file so it throws that error. So you need to download `JDK 1.7`or `JDK 1.8` of Oracle. You can download JDK from here

https://jdk7.java.net/download.html

Answer (score 0):

add new variable to your Environment variables :

computer properties -> advanced system settings -> (tab) advanced -> environment variables ->

(in system variable ) new : variable name = JAVA_HOME , variable value = jdk path

example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

Answer (score 0):

Do Not include \bin when you point to your JDK Location.

Answer (score -1):

1. install jdk-8u25-windows-i586.exe
2. Close android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe
3. Reinstall android-studio-bundle-135.1641136.exe
4. Just -_-